reportlab pdfgen does not create PDF
I need some help on a PDF report creation process I am currently working on, with reportlab.pdfgen on Python 3.10.
I use the following code:
def create_pdf_report(calc_output, project_id):
    pdf_filename = "C:\\Users\\This_User\\Desktop\\Project Calculations\\" + project_id + ".pdf"

    report_canvas = canvas.Canvas(
        pdf_filename,
        pagesize=A4,
    )

    pagewidth, pageheight = A4
    rowheight = 12.5
    textheight = 9

    report_canvas.setFont("Helvetica", textheight)

    for counter in range(int(0.9 * pageheight / rowheight)):

        if counter % 2 == 0:
            report_canvas.setFillColorRGB(1, 0.8, 0.6)
        else:
            report_canvas.setFillColorRGB(0.4, 1, 1)

        report_canvas.rect(
            pagewidth * 0.05,
            pageheight * 0.95 - rowheight * (1 + counter),
            pagewidth * 0.9,
            rowheight,
            stroke=False,
            fill=True,
        )

        report_canvas.setFillColorRGB(0, 0, 0)

        report_canvas.drawString(
            0.075 * pagewidth,
            pageheight * 0.95 - rowheight * (1 + counter) + (rowheight - textheight),
            project_id + ", Line No. " + str(counter + 1)
        )

    report_canvas.showPage()

    report_canvas.save()

    print("Code has completed")

    return

If I run this snippet as a script, i.e., I am just adding the line
create_pdf_report(1, "Hello World Project")

to the bottom of the file and run it, it works perfectly.
But once I call it from another file by
import support_functions as spt

def my_main_function(input):
    # some other code
    calculation_result = 2 * input
    project_string = "Hello World Project"

    spt.create_pdf_report(calculation_result, project_string)

    return calculation_result

my_main_function(1.0)

no PDF is generated. The code runs through to the end without throwing any exceptions, "Code has completed" is printed to the console, but no PDF is generated in the specified place.
Any ideas where I'm making my mistake?
Thanks to all for any help!

Of course, just to be clear, the pdf generation code is saved in the file "support_functions.py" in the same project folder as the main function. Just to be clear that it's not a problem with importing the code.
